# integrating Asp.net Webform and Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net

I have a fully function asp.net MVC application and a fully function asp.net Webform application in the same solution but I want to publish both applications together by integrating them using the same port and session. Any suggestion will be Appreciated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSM05.png)

Comment: Do you have control over the IIS web-server they're installed on? You could keep them as different projects and publish them into different IIS Application Scopes into the same Website. Sharing session data will be harder and probably best done by using an out-of-process session provider instead of combining both projects into the same Web Application Project.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Yes I have the control over the IIS web server they’re installed. I get the concept but I don’t even know if it’s possible to publish multiple application in single website how you publish different IIS Application Scopes into the same Website because the two application has to be connect one another only certain people can access the Mvc application....